# Discrete Ordinal Classification with Probabilities

Tags: machine-learning, xgboost

If I have classes 1, 2, 3 and 4. But, I also need the probability for each of the other classes. I'm currently using XGBoost for one-vs-rest classification, but that means we're losing information since the classes are ordinal.

Comment: can you add a bit more detail to what your question is? if you're just looking for a model for ordinal regression a quick internet search can get you the answer

Comment: @oW_, most ordinal regression only gives the final prediction. I'd prefer a probably for each of 25 discrete classes. So, I need a probably that the y_pred == 1, y_pred == 2 etc.

Answer (score 1):

Probit and logit ordinal regression model the cumulative probabilities $P(y \leq i | x)$. So you should be able to get class probabilities by taking the difference $P(y=i |x) = P(y \leq i|x) - P(y\leq i-1 |x)$. Then it just depends on the implementation whether or not it makes the probabilities available to you.

In `R`, for example, you can get these probabilities from the `polr` package.

[Even though you lose some information when doing one-vs-rest classification, ordinal regression models make some proportionality assumptions that (if not appropriate for your data) may not necessarily give you better results.]

Answer (score 0):

I think for obtaining probabilities for each of the classes you should be doing multiclass classification, instead of one-vs-rest classification. In one-vs-rest classification, the rest of the classes grouped together as one class so getting probabilities for each separately is not possible.

Comment: I can get the probabilities from one-vs-rest just by getting the one-vs-rest probability for each of the classes. But, it's losing the fact that output is ordinal, is losing vital information.